# C# control browser

Tags: c#, autofill

Please suggest how can write c# to control browser to go to url and auto fill in specific element

Comment: you want to redirect your page to other page and than populate a control?? is that you want to do or something else? Can you please elaborate what really you want to do :) !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use WebBrowser Control in C#? Drag the Control from the Toolbar to your Form. Then do `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.example.com/bla");`
fill in the element you want like this: `webBrowser1.Document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = "some content";`

hope this helps,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

Use **WatiN** project to open browser, go to specific page and do the appropriate. Primarily this is a web testing automation tool, but you could (ab)use it for other things as well.

http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Searock: Well it's not just nice... It would solve @tee's problem as well. :D but thanks for your vote.